# How do I request that a work item owner add more details to the work item and keep the history?

Tags: tfs

In TFS, how do I request more information from the owner of a work item and have my request appear in the work item history?

So for example a user submits a bug, then I would like to use TFS to request more information and I would like my request to be within or attached to the bug. Then would like the user to update the bug in a way that I can see the progression.

Similarly is there a way to notify the user that I have updated the bug (without explicitly sending them a manual email)?

So I would like this to be outside the context of a daily standup meeting and a more automated process.

Comment: I ended up just directing users to add comments in the history and I added a rule to email users when an item is updated. It's not as seamless as I would like but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a new state or reason, with a piece of workflow that assigns the work item back to the creator automatically and have a email alert on assigned to changes to [me].  However I normally just manually assign it to someone and ask for more details in the history.

Comment: "However I normally just manually assign it to someone and ask for more details in the history." That's just what I did.